# Order of evaluation of predicates in Spark SQL where clause

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I am trying to understand the order of predicate evaluation in Spark SQL in order to increase performance of a query.
Let's say I have the following query

```
"select * from tbl where pred1 and pred2"
```

and lets say that none of the predicates qualify as pushdown filters (for simplification).
Also lets assume that `pred1` is computationally much more complex than `pred2` (assume regex pattern matching vs negation).

- Is there any way to verify that spark will evaluate `pred2` before
  `pred1`?
- Is this deterministic?
- Is this controllable?
- Is there any way to see the ***final*** execution plan?

Comment: To see the generated plan: `spark.sql("select * from tbl where pred1 and pred2").explain(true)`

Comment: This does not give the final execution plan. explain (extended) gives the: Parsed Logical Plan, Analyzed Logical Plan, Optimized Logical Plan and Physical Plan (not final) so i still can't seem to find the final plan executed

Comment: I have been looking further, this is a tough question and hard to prove.

Comment: I updated the question as best I could based on what I would consider an authorative source with inferencing.

Comment: In non-AQE mode I think I proved that evaluation order of predicates does not matter. I wrote a UDF and along with a simple predicate I wrote the filter / where clause both ways round and counted the calls to the UDF via accum. the accum cnt was equal to num rows in DF. Is that proof for you?

Comment: Have updated the question substantially. Pls look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**General**

Good question.

Inferred answer via testing a scenario and making deductions as could not find the suitable docs. 2nd attempt due to all sorts of statements on the web not able to be backed up.

> This question I think is not about AQE Spark 3.x aspects, but it is
> about say, a dataframe as part of Stage N of a Spark App that has
> passed the stage of acquiring data from sources at rest, which is
> subject to filtering with multiple predicates being applied.
>
> Then the central point is does it matter how the predicates are
> ordered or does Spark (Catalyst) re-order the predicates to minimize
> the work to be done?
>
> - The premise here is that filtering the maximum amount of data out first makes more sense than evaluating a predicate that filters very
>   little out.
>
>   - This is a well-known RDBMS point referring to sargable predicates (subject to evolution of definition over time).
>
>     - A lot of the discussion focused on indexes, Spark, Hive do not have this, but DF's are columnar.

> **Point 1**
>
> You can try for `%sql`
>
> ```
>  EXPLAIN EXTENDED select k, sum(v) from values (1, 2), (1, 3) t(k, v) group by k;
> ```
>
> From this you can see what's going on if there is re-arranging of
> predicates, but I saw no such aspects in the Physical Plan in non-AQE
> mode on Databricks. Refer to
> https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-explain.html.
>
> Catalyst can re-arrange filtering I read here and there. To what
> extent, is a lot of research; I was not able to confirm this.
>
> Also an interesting read:
> https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/catalyst-optimizer-in-spark-sql/read

> **Point 2**
>
> I ran the following pathetic contrived examples with the same
> functional query but with predicates reversed, using a column that has
> high cardinality and tested for a value that does not in fact exist
> and then compared the count of the accumulator used in an UDF when called.

*Scenario 1*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def randomInt1to1000000000 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000000000)+1
def randomInt1to10 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)+1
def randomInt1to1000000 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000000)+1

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq.fill(1000000){(randomInt1to1000000,randomInt1to1000000000,randomInt1to10)}).toDF("nuid","hc", "lc").withColumn("text", lpad($"nuid", 3, "0")).withColumn("literal",lit(1)) 

val accumulator = sc.longAccumulator("udf_call_count")

spark.udf.register("myUdf", (x: String) => {accumulator.add(1)
                                            x.length}
                  )  

accumulator.reset()
df.where("myUdf(text) = 3 and hc = -4").select(max($"text")).show(false)
println(s"Number of UDF calls ${accumulator.value}")
```

returns:

```
+---------+
|max(text)|
+---------+
|null     |
+---------+

Number of UDF calls 1000000
```

*Scenario 2*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def randomInt1to1000000000 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000000000)+1
def randomInt1to10 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(10)+1
def randomInt1to1000000 = scala.util.Random.nextInt(1000000)+1

val dfA = sc.parallelize(Seq.fill(1000000){(randomInt1to1000000,randomInt1to1000000000,randomInt1to10)}).toDF("nuid","hc", "lc").withColumn("text", lpad($"nuid", 3, "0")).withColumn("literal",lit(1)) 

val accumulator = sc.longAccumulator("udf_call_count")

spark.udf.register("myUdf", (x: String) => {accumulator.add(1)
                                            x.length}
                  )  

accumulator.reset()
dfA.where("hc = -4 and myUdf(text) = 3").select(max($"text")).show(false)
println(s"Number of UDF calls ${accumulator.value}")
```

returns:

```
+---------+
|max(text)|
+---------+
|null     |
+---------+

Number of UDF calls 0
```

My conclusion here is that:

- There is left to right evaluation - in this case - as there are 0 calls for the udf as the accumulator value is 0 for scenario 2, as opposed to scenario 1 with 1M calls registered.
- So, the order of predicate processing as say ORACLE and DB2 may do for Stage 1 predicates does not apply.

> **Point 3**
>
> I note from the manual however
> https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-scala.html the
> following:
>
> **Evaluation order and null checking**
>
> Spark SQL (including SQL and the DataFrame and Dataset APIs) does not
> guarantee the order of evaluation of subexpressions. In particular,
> the inputs of an operator or function are not necessarily evaluated
> left-to-right or in any other fixed order. For example, logical AND
> and OR expressions do not have left-to-right “short-circuiting”
> semantics.
>
> Therefore, it is dangerous to rely on the side effects or order of
> evaluation of Boolean expressions, and the order of WHERE and HAVING
> clauses, since such expressions and clauses can be reordered during
> query optimization and planning. Specifically, if a UDF relies on
> short-circuiting semantics in SQL for null checking, there’s no
> guarantee that the null check will happen before invoking the UDF. For
> example,
>
> ```
> spark.udf.register("strlen", (s: String) => s.length)
> spark.sql("select s from test1 where s is not null and strlen(s) > 1") // no guarantee
> ```
>
> This WHERE clause does not guarantee the strlen UDF to be invoked
> after filtering out nulls.
>
> To perform proper null checking, we recommend that you do either of
> the following:
>
> Make the UDF itself null-aware and do null checking inside the UDF
> itself Use IF or CASE WHEN expressions to do the null check and invoke
> the UDF in a conditional branch.
>
> ```
> spark.udf.register("strlen_nullsafe", (s: String) => if (s != null) s.length else -1)
> spark.sql("select s from test1 where s is not null and strlen_nullsafe(s) > 1") // ok
> spark.sql("select s from test1 where if(s is not null, strlen(s), null) > 1")   // ok
> ```
>
> Slight contradiction.

Comment: unfortunately explain (extended) only gives the: Parsed Logical Plan, Analyzed Logical Plan, Optimized Logical Plan and Physical Plan (not final) so i still can't seem to find the final plan executed.

Comment: OK - can i assume that the order of the filters in the physical plan is the order of execution? there is no reference in the docs for that.

Comment: BTW - im running on azure databricks and the output for the extended explain on my df (in regards to the physical plan) is: 
`== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false`
meaning (if they have'nt lied to me) - the only physical plan - isn't the final plan.

Comment: ah, but that does not apply to your question as such.

Comment: In non-AQE mode I think I proved that evaluation order of predicates does not matter. I wrote a UDF and along with a simple predicate I wrote the filter / where clause both ways round and counted the calls to the UDF via accum. the accum cnt was equal to num rows in DF. Is that proof for you?